# Same alpha on legend and plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha

My data:

```
structure(list(month = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
"07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"), p00pcp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), p20pcp = c(7.8, 12.8, 12.9, 18.9, 17.8, 
5.7, 0.2, 0.9, 6.6, 14.4, 16.8, 12.3), p40pcp = c(20.3, 26.4, 
27, 34.7, 29.9, 19, 3.9, 3.4, 12.7, 33.6, 43.2, 25.4), p50pcp = c(27.5, 
32.5, 33.7, 45.6, 35.7, 24.5, 6, 6.1, 17, 48.8, 48.3, 32.9), 
    p60pcp = c(34.2, 41, 41.6, 52.9, 45.6, 28.9, 9.2, 9.1, 25.6, 
    58.5, 60.2, 45.5), p80pcp = c(64.4, 63, 58, 69.8, 71, 40.8, 
    16.5, 15.3, 47.5, 86.9, 79.7, 79.1), p100pcp = c(156.1, 128.7, 
    140.7, 138.1, 135.3, 91.9, 54.8, 73.8, 169, 192.4, 198.4, 
    180.5), sumpcp = c(11.7, 1.6, 22, 8.3, 58.6, 42.5, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.1, NA), diffp50pcp = c("-15.8", "-30.9", "-11.7", 
    "-37.3", "+22.9", "+18", "-6", "-6.1", "-17", "-48.8", "-48.2", 
    NA), diffp50pcp_x = c("/2.4", "/20.3", "/1.5", "/5.5", "x1.6", 
    "x1.7", "-", "-", "-", "-", "/483", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My code so far:

```
ref_end_year <- 2010
ref_start_year <- 1981
selected_year <- 2020    

ggplot2::ggplot(data = plot_data, aes(x = month)) +
    ggh4x::geom_box(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = p00pcp, fill = "P00", width = 0.9), alpha = 0.3) +
    ggh4x::geom_box(aes(ymin = p00pcp, ymax = p20pcp, fill = "P20", width = 0.9), alpha = 0.3) +
    ggh4x::geom_box(aes(ymin = p20pcp, ymax = p40pcp, fill = "P40", width = 0.9), alpha = 0.3) +
    ggh4x::geom_box(aes(ymin = p40pcp, ymax = p60pcp, fill = "P60", width = 0.9), alpha = 0.3) +
    ggh4x::geom_box(aes(ymin = p60pcp, ymax = p80pcp, fill = "P80", width = 0.9), alpha = 0.3) +
    ggh4x::geom_box(aes(ymin = p80pcp, ymax = p100pcp, fill = "P100", width = 0.9), alpha = 0.3) +
    ggh4x::geom_box(aes(ymin = p100pcp, ymax = p100pcp + 50, fill = ">P100", width = 0.9), alpha = 0.3) +
    ggplot2::geom_segment(aes(x = month, xend = month, y = 0, yend = sumpcp, color = "sumpcp"), 
                          linewidth = 0.75, na.rm = TRUE) +
    ggplot2::geom_point(aes(y = sumpcp, color = "sumpcp"), na.rm = TRUE) +
    ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values = c("sumpcp" = "black"),
                                label = paste0("Monthly total precip. (", selected_year, ")"), 
                                guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
    ggplot2::geom_text(aes(y = sumpcp, label = paste(diffmedian, "*mm~vs.~italic(P)[50]")), 
                       parse = TRUE, vjust = -2.5, na.rm = TRUE) +
    ggplot2::geom_text(aes(y = sumpcp, label = diffmedian_x), vjust = -1.5, na.rm = TRUE) +
    #ggplot2::scale_alpha_manual(values = rep(0.3, 1)) +
    ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(
      values = c(">P100" = "#2166ac", "P100" = "#67a9cf", "P80" = "#d1e5f0", "P60" = "#f7f7f7", "P40" = "#fddbc7", 
                 "P20" = "#ef8a62", "P00" = "#b2182b"),
      labels = c(">P100" = expr(paste("Extrem. wet month (>", italic(P[100]), ") (", 
                                     !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")")), 
                 "P100" = expr(paste("Very wet month (", italic(P[80]), "-", italic(P[100]), ") (", 
                                     !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")")), 
                 "P80" = expr(paste("Wet month (", italic(P[60]), "-", italic(P[80]), ") (", 
                                    !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")")), 
                 "P60" = expr(paste("Normal month (", italic(P[40]), "-", italic(P[60]), ") (", 
                                    !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")")),
                 "P40" = expr(paste("Dry month (", italic(P[20]), "-", italic(P[40]), ") (", 
                                    !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")")),
                 "P20" = expr(paste("Very dry month (", italic(P[00]), "-", italic(P[20]), ") (", 
                                    !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")")),
                 "P00" = expr(paste("Extrem. dry month (<", italic(P[00]), ") (", 
                                    !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")"))),
      breaks = c(">P100", "P100", "P80", "P60", "P40", "P20", "P00")) + # to give order
    ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(
      limits = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"),
      labels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")) +
    ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(
      labels = function(x) paste0(x, "mm"),
      breaks = seq(from = 0, to = max(max(plot_data$p100pcp), max(plot_data$sumpcp, na.rm = TRUE)) + 125, by = 50),
      limits = c(0, max(max(plot_data$p100pcp), max(plot_data$sumpcp, na.rm = TRUE)) + 100)) +
    ggthemes::theme_hc(base_size = 15) +
    ggplot2::labs(
      x = "", y = "",
      color = NULL, fill = NULL
    ) +
    ggplot2::theme(
      plot.title = ggplot2::element_text(hjust = 1, face = "bold", family = "sans", size = 35),
      plot.subtitle = ggplot2::element_text(hjust = 1, size = 25),
      legend.background = ggplot2::element_blank(),
      legend.box.background = ggplot2::element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black", linewidth = 0.75),
      legend.position = c(0.125, 0.85),
      legend.spacing = ggplot2::unit(0, "cm"),
      legend.margin = ggplot2::margin(r = 5, l = 5, b = 5),
      legend.title = ggplot2::element_blank()
    )
```

As you can see, alpha is not applied on the legend, only in the main plot. How can I apply same alpha to legend boxes? To be clear: I want same color transparency within the legend boxes and the ones in `geom_box`. I've tried including alpha inside `aes()` and use `scale_alpha_manual()` with no luck. I have also tried `+ guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))` but with no luck either. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Surely you want `+ guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0.3)))` instead of `alpha = 1` if you want the legend to match the bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a prime example of the mysterious issues one might encounter when working and plotting with untidy data. (;

The issue is a special kind of overplotting which only happens in the legend, i.e. for each of your `geom_box` layers a legend key is drawn, i.e. in total for each category 7 legend keys are drawn on top each other, each with an `alpha` of .3. But in "sum" it seems as if no `alpha` is applied. This is also the reason why overriding `alpha` via `guides` will have no effect (but perhaps `override.aes(alpha = .3 / 7)` gets you close).

Instead, reshape your data to long and create your chart using just one e.g. `geom_col`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

plot_data_long <- plot_data |>
  select(month, matches("^>?p")) |>
  select(-p50pcp) |>
  mutate(
    `>p100pcp` = p100pcp + 50,
  ) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    -month
  ) |>
  mutate(
    name = toupper(gsub("pcp$", "", name)),
    name = factor(name, levels = rev(unique(name)))
  ) |>
  arrange(month) |>
  mutate(
    value = value - dplyr::lag(value, default = 0),
    .by = month
  )

ggplot(data = plot_data_long, aes(x = month)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = value, fill = name), width = 0.9, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_segment(
    data = plot_data,
    aes(
      x = month, xend = month,
      y = 0, yend = sumpcp, color = "sumpcp"
    ),
    linewidth = 0.75, na.rm = TRUE
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = plot_data,
    aes(y = sumpcp, color = "sumpcp"), na.rm = TRUE
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("sumpcp" = "black"),
    label = paste0("Monthly total precip. (", selected_year, ")"),
    guide = guide_legend(order = 1)
  ) +
  # geom_text(aes(y = sumpcp, label = paste(diffmedian, "*mm~vs.~italic(P)[50]")),
  #   parse = TRUE, vjust = -2.5, na.rm = TRUE
  # ) +
  # geom_text(aes(y = sumpcp, label = diffmedian_x), vjust = -1.5, na.rm = TRUE) +
  # scale_alpha_manual(values = rep(0.3, 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      ">P100" = "#2166ac", "P100" = "#67a9cf",
      "P80" = "#d1e5f0", "P60" = "#f7f7f7",
      "P40" = "#fddbc7",
      "P20" = "#ef8a62", "P00" = "#b2182b"
    ),
    labels = c(
      ">P100" = expr(paste(
        "Extrem. wet month (>", italic(P[100]), ") (",
        !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")"
      )),
      "P100" = expr(paste(
        "Very wet month (", italic(P[80]), "-", italic(P[100]), ") (",
        !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")"
      )),
      "P80" = expr(paste(
        "Wet month (", italic(P[60]), "-", italic(P[80]), ") (",
        !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")"
      )),
      "P60" = expr(paste(
        "Normal month (", italic(P[40]), "-", italic(P[60]), ") (",
        !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")"
      )),
      "P40" = expr(paste(
        "Dry month (", italic(P[20]), "-", italic(P[40]), ") (",
        !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")"
      )),
      "P20" = expr(paste(
        "Very dry month (", italic(P[00]), "-", italic(P[20]), ") (",
        !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")"
      )),
      "P00" = expr(paste(
        "Extrem. dry month (<", italic(P[00]), ") (",
        !!ref_start_year, "-", !!ref_end_year, ")"
      ))
    )
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = month.abb
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = function(x) paste0(x, "mm"),
    breaks = seq(from = 0, to = max(
      max(plot_data$p100pcp),
      max(plot_data$sumpcp, na.rm = TRUE)
    ) + 125, by = 50),
    limits = c(0, max(
      max(plot_data$p100pcp),
      max(plot_data$sumpcp, na.rm = TRUE)
    ) + 100)
  ) +
  ggthemes::theme_hc(base_size = 15) +
  labs(
    x = "", y = "",
    color = NULL, fill = NULL
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(
      hjust = 1, face = "bold", family = "sans", size = 35
    ),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 25),
    legend.background = element_blank(),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(
      fill = "white", color = "black", linewidth = 0.75
    ),
    legend.position = c(0.125, 0.85),
    legend.spacing = unit(0, "cm"),
    legend.margin = margin(r = 5, l = 5, b = 5),
    legend.title = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]